# regex_replace not working as expected

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

We are using

```
regexp_replace(string,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)','');
```

This is not only removing unprintable characters from string and tabs from beginning and in between but also removing leading lowercase 't' if it is present in string as `\t` is also regex for lower case 't'.

For example, if I provide string value to be `'  Q W E R T Y'` or `' T W E E T'` it  works perfectly fine and provide us the value `'QWERTY'` and `'TWEET'` respectively.

But if I provide an input `' t WEE    T'` , it returns `'WEET'` as an output.

Please let me know the solution for this as this is completely undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Oracle/String_Functions/REGEXP_REPLACE_function.htm), it doesn't look like `\t` is supported.

Since you seem to be trimming blank space as well, have you considered using `[:blank:]` or `\s`.

If it is strictly tab characters you need to identify it looks like you could use:

```
'([[:cntrl:]])|(^' || CHR(9) || ')'
```